# Multiple coins transfer via aptos smart contract

Tags: aptos

Please help me. How to send several different coins at once using a smart contract to Aptos in one transaction if initially the number of coins and their types are unknown and will be indicated only by arguments? I realized that I should use vectors in the function arguments, but I can’t figure it out further.

I've tried to use vectors like in code below but i got errors.

```
public entry fun multisend(sender: &signer, receiver: address, types: vector<coin::Coin<T>>, amounts: vector<u64>)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible because:

- to transfer `Coin`, you must pass `CoinType`: `coin::transfer<CoinType>(sender, receiver, amount);`
- however, passing an unknown amount of `CoinType` as type arguments is impossible. The best you can do is `multisend<CoinType1, CoinType2, ..., CoinTypeN>` but N is a bounded number.